# dhclient on mac os x

Tags: mac

what is equivalent of dhclient command in mac os x?

Answer (score 8):

Darwin/Mac OS doesn't run separate processes to handle obtaining DHCP code, instead all handling of DHCP leases, &c, is handled by the IPConfiguration agent.  As users, our interface to this is through ipconfig.

If you want information on a DHCP lease, `ipconfig getpacket`*interface* (e.g., `en0`, `en1`), will give you the full lease packet it received from the server; e.g.:

```
op = BOOTREPLY
htype = 1
dp_flags = 0
hlen = 6
hops = 0
xid = 272692599
secs = 0
ciaddr = 0.0.0.0
yiaddr = 192.168.0.102
siaddr = 0.0.0.0
giaddr = 0.0.0.0
chaddr = 0:11:24:a2:7:87
sname = 
file = 
options:
Options count is 7
dhcp_message_type (uint8): ACK 0x5
server_identifier (ip): 192.168.0.1
lease_time (uint32): 0xd2f00
subnet_mask (ip): 255.255.255.0
router (ip_mult): {192.168.0.1}
domain_name_server (ip_mult): {192.168.0.1}
end (none):
```

Answer (score 1):

did you just want to renew your ip? if so have a look at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/86956/release-renew-ip-address-via-terminal-in-os-x) question.

hope this helps